# Do we GroupBy and Sum explicitly on Level 0 in MultiIndex Dataframe? Now I am getting Empty DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm struggling a bit with a new concept, which I just recently stumbled upon recently.  I'm trying to work with a MultiIndex Dataframe.  I have two rows of headers in this dataframe, and I really need both headers matching up, just as they do when I import the data from the CSV file.

Here is my MultiIndex DF:

```
      index             IDRSSD                             RCFD3531  \
            Unnamed: 0_level_1 TRDG ASSETS-US TREAS SECS IN DOM OFF   
0         0                 37                                  0.0   
1         1                242                                  0.0   
2         2                279                                  0.0   
3         3                354                                  0.0   
4         4                457                                  0.0   
    ...                ...                                  ...   
21380  7080            4232881                                  0.0   
21381  7081            4257594                                  0.0   
21382  7082            4262534                                  0.0   
21383  7083            4262543                                  0.0   
21384  7084            4368351                                  0.0   

                               RCFD3532  ...  \
      TRDG ASSETS-US GOV AGC CORP OBLGS  ...   
0                                   0.0  ...   
1                                   0.0  ...   
2                                   0.0  ...   
3                                   0.0  ...   
4                                   0.0  ...   
                                ...  ...   
21380                               0.0  ...   
21381                               0.0  ...   
21382                               0.0  ...   
21383                               0.0  ...   
21384                               0.0  ...   

                                           file schedule_code        year  \
                                                                            
0      FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312011.txt           RCD  03/31/2011   
1      FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312011.txt           RCD  03/31/2011   
2      FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312011.txt           RCD  03/31/2011   
3      FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312011.txt           RCD  03/31/2011   
4      FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312011.txt           RCD  03/31/2011   
                                        ...           ...         ...   
21380  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312013.txt           RCD  03/31/2013   
21381  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312013.txt           RCD  03/31/2013   
21382  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312013.txt           RCD  03/31/2013   
21383  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312013.txt           RCD  03/31/2013   
21384  FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCD 03312013.txt           RCD  03/31/2013   

        qyear  
               
0      2011Q1  
1      2011Q1  
2      2011Q1  
3      2011Q1  
4      2011Q1  
      ...  
21380  2013Q1  
21381  2013Q1  
21382  2013Q1  
21383  2013Q1  
21384  2013Q1  

[21385 rows x 145 columns]
```

The import is done like this; I think this is correct.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t', skiprows=0, header=[0,1])
```

I think the issue is with the way I am doing the GroupBy and Sum.  Here is the code that I am testing.

```
grouped_and_summed = df_append.stack().reset_index().groupby(['IDRSSD','qyear']).sum()
```

I want to GroupBy these two fields: `'IDRSSD','qyear'` and Sum all the other fields.

When I run the code above and check the `grouped_and_summed` variable, I see only this.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [level_0, RCFD3531, RCFD3532, RCFD3533, RCFD3541, RCFD3543, RCFD3545, RCFD3546, RCFD3547, RCFD3548, RCFDF610, RCFDF614, RCFDF615, RCFDF616, RCFDF618, RCFDF624, RCFDF632, RCFDF633, RCFDF634, RCFDF636, RCFDF639, RCFDF640, RCFDF643, RCFDF644, RCFDF645, RCFDF646, RCFDF647, RCFDF648, RCFDF651, RCFDF652, RCFDF653, RCFDF654, RCFDF655, RCFDF656, RCFDF657, RCFDF658, RCFDF659, RCFDF660, RCFDF790, RCFDG299, RCFDG332, RCFDG333, RCFDG334, RCFDG335, RCFDG379, RCFDG380, RCFDG381, RCFDG383, RCFDG384, RCFDG385, RCFDG386, RCFDG387, RCFDG388, RCFDG651, RCFDG652, RCFDK197, RCFDK198, RCFDK199, RCFDK200, RCFDK210, RCFDK211, RCON3531, RCON3532, RCON3533, RCON3541, RCON3543, RCON3545, RCON3546, RCON3547, RCON3548, RCONF604, RCONF605, RCONF606, RCONF607, RCONF611, RCONF612, RCONF613, RCONF614, RCONF615, RCONF616, RCONF618, RCONF624, RCONF625, RCONF626, RCONF627, RCONF628, RCONF629, RCONF630, RCONF631, RCONF632, RCONF633, RCONF634, RCONF636, RCONF639, RCONF640, RCONF643, RCONF644, RCONF645, RCONF646, RCONF647, ...]
Index: []

[0 rows x 141 columns]
```

I feel like the `'IDRSSD','qyear'` are on level 0 and they are getting skipped, but I don't know for sure if that's right.  Under `IDRSSD` I have this: `Unnamed: 0_level_1`.  In the CSV file, this is totally blank.  Under `qyear` I have another blank.  Do I need to fill `IDRSSD` and `qyear` down, from level 0 to level 1?  Or, do I need ot do the GroupBy and Sum based on level 0 and skip level 1?  I don't really know how to deal with this setup.

I think I went off on a few tangents before, but I feel like I'm back on track now.  I just need to get this last step working, and lock this thing down, once and for all.

Finally, I tried to import both headers, and then strip out level 0 or level 1, and played with that concept a bit, but I didn't make much progress there, as I couldn't easily recombine those two headers after I separated them.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.